# Vuejs : Content replaced after rendering a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, components, vue-component

I'm starting to learn VuesJS and I found an interesting thing.

I've created a page component (*hello-page.js*) and two real components (*Hello.vue* and *Test.vue*). My page component doesn't have a template because I explicitly define it into my twig page. This one is composed with some texts and my real components.

I've noticed that I have to separate my component with `<div></div>`, otherwise the content following a component will not be displayed (in the current div).

I did some research but I didn't find a similar problem. As I said, it is my first project with VueJS so it is possible that I didn't get a particularity of the framework.

Thank you in advance for your help.

### Rendered content

[image: rendered content]

### Expected rendering

[image: expected rendering]

### My page component

```js
// ./components/hello-page.js

import Hello from "./Hello.vue";
import Test from "./Test.vue";

export default {
    name: "HelloPage",
    components: {
        Hello,
        Test
    }
}
```

### My real components

```
// ./components/Hello.vue

<template>
    <div id="hello">
        <p>This is my Hello component</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Hello"
    }
</script>
```

```
// ./components/Test.vue

<template>
    <div id="test">
        <p>This is my Test component</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Test"
    };
</script>
```

### The index file

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import router from "./router";

Vue.component('hello-page', require('./components/hello-page.js').default);

new Vue({
    router
}).$mount("#app");
```

### The twig file

```html
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <hello-page inline-template v-cloak>
        <div>
            <h1>My title</h1>
            <div>
                <Test/>
                <p>This text will not be displayed</p>
            </div>
            <p>This text will be displayed</p>
            <Hello/>
        </div>
    </hello-page>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Try using `<Test></Test>` and `<Hello></Hello>`

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help ! It's working !
For more information about self-closing element : https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1036